# Pass javascript array from file.xhtml to php array using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays

I have 2 pages which are `file.xhtml` and `submit-exec.php`.
I am passing my javascript array from the xhtml file to the php using ajax.
I found several tutorials online but none of them settled my problems.
I am still wondering is it possible any problem with xhtml?

the array:

```
var array = [];
array.push({ name: "name", value: document.forms["form"]["name"].value});
array.push({ name: "email", value: document.forms["form"]["email"].value});
array.push({ name: "mobile", value: document.forms["form"]["mobile"].value});
```

file.xhtml

```
$.ajax({ //to run exec in background
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'submit-exec.php',
    data: {'data' : array},

    success: function(){
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

submit-exec.php

```
$myArray = $_POST['data'];

print_r($myArray);
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You've posted some code that, aside from `array` being undefined, works. What's the problem? What happens that differs from what you expect to happen?

Comment: You need to JSONify your data before sending (data: {'data' : array.serialize()} - I think) and then convert back to an object that php understands (json_decode($_POST{'data']) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send an object (I don't change the variable name "array" to fit your ajax, but you definitily should)

```
var array = {name: document.forms["form"]["name"].value, email: document.forms["form"]["email"].value, mobile: document.forms["form"]["mobile"].value}
```

no need to convert to string

Answer (score -1):

Object can't be send through POST. So, to make your code works you must convert your array to string & convert it back to array at server side. For example:

```
data: {'data' : array.join(',')},
```

And at server side, convert it back to array by using explode:

```
$myArray = explode(",", $_POST['data']);
```